# Googlebot crawling 301 redirected URLs again and again

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect

We're having some problems with our site www.inzoco.com.

There are lots of old URLs being crawled again and again, even if we send a 301 code.

We have checked the entire site several times with a link checker, and there are no traces of those URLs being generated anywhere, but googlebot insist and try to get them every day.

We have no idea of where is the bot finding those old URLs (any way to know this?) or if, somehow, it doesn't see the redirection.

This is one of the old URLs:

http://www.inzoco.com/crits/2-5-5-28-0-0-28074-0-0/listado-bar-en-alquiler-en-leganes-madrid.aspx

redirected with 301 Moved permanently to:

http://www.inzoco.com/crits/2-5-5-28-24-0-28074-0-0/listado-bar-en-alquiler-en-leganes-madrid.aspx

¿Any clue?

Comment: For my website it took 2 years before Googlebot stopped hitting the old pages. Its a normal operation for Googlebot to prevent  accidental redirects. Make sure that you send the 301 and you will be find. Just some extra hits on your webserver from Googlebot

Answer (score 2):

Your `Location` header says:

`/crits/2-5-5-28-24-0-28074-0-0/listado-bar-en-alquiler-en-leganes-madrid.aspx`

This not an URI, just a path. Try a [valid `Location` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30):

```
http://www.inzoco.com/crits/2-5-5-28-24-0-28074-0-0/listado-bar-en-alquiler-en-leganes-madrid.aspx
```